# Wrapping Text in Ordered List

Tags: css, html-lists

I have customized the appearance of the numbers in my ol. Now I can't figure out how to make list items that are multiple lines long stay indented to the same point as the first line. The text is wrapping under the numbers.

I had the same issue with unordered lists but fixed using this in CSS:

```
ul.indentedList li {

    list-style-position: outside;
    margin-left: 1em;

}
```

But I can't make this work with the customized ordered list.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
.custom-counter ol{
counter-reset: myCounter;
}

.custom-counter li{
list-style: none;
counter-increment: step-counter;
}

.custom-counter li:before {
content:counter(step-counter);
color: white;
background: #ff5100;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
margin: 5px 10px;
line-height: 40px;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

And the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aLkvwu84/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated based on comment feedback. I decided to use `flex` and made it work the way I think you're looking for, take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scarsam/dnq9cpyb/)

### This is what I added:

```
.custom-counter li{
  display: flex; 
}
.custom-counter li:before {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
}
// To remove the added margin on top of the paragraph.
.custom-counter li p {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would normally acheive this by absolute positioning the :before to the left of the li's and add padding to the li's to give them consistent indentation. I've added a min-height to the li also to make sure there's always vertical space for the :before

```css
.custom-counter ol{
counter-reset: myCounter;

}

.custom-counter li{
list-style: none;
counter-increment: step-counter;
position: relative;
margin: 20px 0;
padding-left: 50px;
min-height: 40px;
}

.custom-counter li:before {
content:counter(step-counter);
position: absolute;
left:0;
 
color: white;
background: #ff5100;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
line-height: 40px;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ol class="custom-counter">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dictum mauris felis, eget posuere leo congue quis. Mauris mollis nec sem ac volutpat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nam tempor libero a purus congue, efficitur aliquam erat tincidunt.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dictum mauris felis, eget posuere leo congue quis. Mauris mollis nec sem ac volutpat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nam tempor libero a purus congue, efficitur aliquam erat tincidunt.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dictum mauris felis, eget posuere leo congue quis. Mauris mollis nec sem ac volutpat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nam tempor libero a purus congue, efficitur aliquam erat tincidunt.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dictum mauris felis, eget posuere leo congue quis. Mauris mollis nec sem ac volutpat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nam tempor libero a purus congue, efficitur aliquam erat tincidunt. </li>
</ol>
```